# Redirect to Action from within a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In most of the Actions in my controller I need to check to see if a condition has been meet, and if not redirect the user to another Action in the same controller so I tried:

```
    public ActionResult Transactions()
    {
        GrossGalsConfermation();
        return View();
    }

    public void GrossGalsConfermation()
    {
        if (Session["HasConfirmed"] == null && TerminalUserData.IsGrossGallonTerminal)
        {
            RedirectToAction("ConversionFactors");
        }
    }
```

but even when the `if` statement is true the `RedirectToAction` is not executed. I have done a debug in VS and can see it jump from the `Action` to the `Method`, evaluate the `IF` statement and go into it to run the `RedirectToAction` but then it jumps right back to the calling `Acation` and return's it's view. How can I force it to redirect? Searching on line I find similar problems and the solution was to change from `void` to `ActionResult` but then I have to provide an fallback `Action` to return which can not be done since this `Method` will be called by dozens of views.

Comment: What happens if you take out the `if`? Does it redirect to the action?

Comment: @IanAuld It won't - you have to *return* the `RedirectToRouteResult` if you want the browser to redirect.

Comment: It looks like you using helper method instead of action filter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `RedirectToAction` does is return a `RedirectToRouteResult` - the browser won't be redirected unless you actually return it. Since you don't want to do this within your method (you *could* return null and do null checks in your action but it would be clumsy), I'd suggest using an action filter instead. Something like the following would do it:

```
public class GrossGalsFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Session["HasConfirmed"] == null
                                    && TerminalUserData.IsGrossGallonTerminal)
        {
            filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                { controller = "MyController", action = "ConversionFactors" }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then decorate your controller actions:

```
[GrossGalsFilter]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction
```

Note that you may have to modify the filter to get hold of `TerminalUserData.IsGrossGallonTerminal` - impossible to know where this comes from based on your question.

More on action filters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about an action filter. When I return to work on Monday I will convert to an action filter and see how that works.

Comment: I was looking over this today and was just wondering how I would be able to figure out what controller was originally called. So I can pass them back after they complete the needed steps in the ConversionFactors View. I know it was not in the original request but I just realized it today (I can make this a separate question if that is more appropriate)

Comment: Easiest way would be to add a return URL to the redirect as a GET parameter. You can instantiate a UrlHelper to retrieve the appropriate URL dynamically.

Comment: When I do a `New RouteValueDictionary` I get the error System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary does not contain a definition for controller"

Comment: Figured out the route problem, need to do `(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller =`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "return":

```
return RedirectToAction(...);
```

If you want to reuse the method multiple times you should look into writing a filter.

Comment: Read the question fully. *Searching on line I find similar problems and the solution was to change from void to ActionResult but then I have to provide an fallback Action to return which can not be done since this Method will be called by dozens of views.*

Comment: You still need to return ActionResult.

Comment: Your answer does not address the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your `GrossGalsConfirmation()` (it's spelled with an i not an e btw) doesn't return anything. Change it's return type to `ActionResult` and return the `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: From OP: Searching on line I find similar problems and the solution was to change from void to ActionResult but then I have to provide an fallback Action to return which can not be done since this Method will be called by dozens of views.